# regexp to quote only string matches (not numbers)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling with string:

```
"some text [2string] some another[test] and another [4]";
```

trying to quote every value but number within [], so it could be converted into

```
"some text ['2string'] some another['test'] and another [4]"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us some of the things you have tried, if any?

Comment: string.split('[').join("['").split(']').join("']") but it quotes numbers also

Comment: Try `"some text [2string] some another[test] and another [4]".replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, function(val, g1){ return '[' + (/^\d+$/.test(g1) ? g1: "'" + g1+ "'") + ']'})`

Comment: What about `decimal numbers like [4.5]?` Quote them or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a regex that

- matches content between `[]`, i. e. a `[`, any number of characters except `]`, then a `]`
- asserts that there is at least one other character besides digits here.

You can solve this using [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
result = subject.replace(/\[(?!\d+\])([^\]]*)\]/g, "['$1']");
```

**Explanation:**

```
\[      # Match [
(?!     # Assert that it's impossible to match...
 \d+    # one or more digits
 \]     # followed by ]
)       # End of lookahead assertion
(       # Match and capture in group number 1:
 [^\]]* # any number of characters except ]
)       # End of capturing group
\]      # Match ]
```

Comment: is `positive lookahead assertions` supported in all browsers

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Yes. Only lookbehind assertions aren't supported by JavaScript (I changed my plan and used a *negative* lookahead, that turned out to be easier; but it's the same for both kinds).

Comment: I actually like this approach, the only part I don't really like is the fact that you essentially walk through the supposed placeholder twice (first to satisfy the lookahead, then for the real match; assume something like `[234290127402z]`). But guess that can be neglected.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like `\[(\d*?[a-z]\w*?)]`. This should match any `[...]` as long as there's at least one letter inside. If underscores (`_`) aren't valid, replace the `\w` at the end with `[a-z]`.

- `\[` is just a simple match for `[`, it has to be escaped due to the special meaning of `[`.
- `\d*?` will match any amount of digits (or none), but as few as possible to fulfill the match.
- `[a-z]` will match any character within the given range.
- `\w*?` will match any "word" (alphanumeric) characters (letters, digits, and underscores), again as few as possible to fulfill the match.
- `]` is another simple match, this one doesn't have to be escaped, as it's not misleading (no open `[` at this level). It can be escaped, but this is usually a style preference (depends on the actual regex engine).

Answer (score 0):

A longer, but IMO cleaner approach, if performance is *not* a big concern:

```
var string = "some text [2string] some another[test] and another [4]";
var output =  string.replace(/(\[)(.*?)(\])/g, function(match, a, b, c) {
  if(/^\d+$/.test(b)) {
    return match;
  } else {
    return a + "'" + b + "'" + c;
  }
});
console.log(output);
```

You basically match  every expression inside square brackets, then test to see if it's a number. If it is, return the string as-it-is, otherwise insert quotes at the specific places.

Output:

```
some text ['2string'] some another['test'] and another [4]
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that this requires the evaluation of two regular expressions rather than having one expression being a little bit longer. Not sure I'd call that "cleaner". It's definitely easier to understand for someone starting with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it with this regex

```
input.replace(/(?!\d+\])(\w+)(?=\])/g, "'$1'");
```

Comment: Won't work; you're not capturing anything here, so `$1` will appear literally in the output.

Answer (score 0):

another solution that add a simple regex to your attempt:

```
str.split('[').join("['").split(']').join("']").replace(/\['(\d+)'\]/, "[$1]");
```